# NetBeans 8.0.2 : form can't be main class

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point, netbeans-8

I made ​​a simple program input and data display connected to sql server 2008. Only one java class for connections (KoneksiDatabase.java) and one JFrame form for form (Form.Java). Previously I did not specify the main class for the project . after JFrame form completed I made why I could not make out the form as the main class ?
when I create a new form JFrame (Form2.java) form they will be made in the main class in the Project Properties

Form2.Java only seen in pictures that can be made in the main class , while Form.Java can not.

http://s.kaskus.id/images/2015/08/11/912158_20150811050000.jpg

Comment: Link seems to be broken? Do both classes have a public static void main() function?

Comment: in my code form.java class is private , I change into public and solved now . Sorry my fault for not carefully :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this in your Form class?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Form().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

or even more simpler

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   new Form().setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: in my code form.java class is private , I change into public and solved now . Sorry my fault for not carefully :)